# How to call a method from a second class to act on an object of third class

Tags: ruby, class, oop, object, methods

I'm making a TicTacToe game in Ruby, whose implementation looks something like this.

```
class Board
  @grid #an array which holds Xs, Os and nils.
  def won? #checks if the game has been won
  def mark_move #implements a given move for a player
  #other methods....
end

class Player
  def initialize #to initialize player name etc.

  def move
    ....
  mark = gets.chomp.split(",").map(&:to_i)
  #How to do this?
  #I want this method to call mark_move on the initiated object of Board class 
  end

end

class Game
  def initialize(p1, p2) #p1, p2 are objects of Player class
    board = Board.new
  end

  def play
    puts "Welcome to game....."
    loop until won?
      p1.move #How to make this act on the board object?
      board.grid.display
      return if won?
      p2.move ##How to make this act on the board object?
    end
    puts winner
  end
end
```

The solution that I want is to make the move method in Player class act on the object of Board class (board). What could be the best way to do this? pass the board as an argument from the Game class? (p1.move(board)) That doesn't look optimal because I'm imagining a bigger problem where we could have like 10-15 classes and we want their methods to act on different objects. If we were to solve that using passing object arguments everytime, it'd create a real mess...

What the expert way to solve problems like these?

Thx!

Comment: Invert it, board.move(p1) ? Or perhaps BoardMovement(board, p1).  All depends of what you want to put where. If it could be some this way and some that, then some sort of intermediate, or may be some meta code. Though that seems a bit heavy for TicTacToe

Comment: @TonyHopkinson the reason why I think that's not a good idea is that we want to insulate our Board class from any of the game logic. Hence, I'm against creating a move method in the Board class. We just want it to be concern it basic rules and displaying states etc. The Game class should just contain the flow of the game and similarly the Player class should do everything related to making a move.

Comment: Got to be careful. There's Board as in array of pieces. There's board as in display representation, and theres board as in movement constraints. Could easily be three different classes.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the optimal solution is passing arguments, just keep it simple...

`p1.move(board)` seems good to me...

But for my implementation it would be(basing on your current code):

```
def play
  ...   
  board.mark_move(p1.move)
  ...
end
```

This would be the simplest, fastest, and most readable solution for me :)

Comment: Well don't you think that the first approach (p1.move(board)) would be better? Since that way we could do other stuff (e.g. check if the move is legal) inside the move method of player rather than in the game class' play method? Because the second approach wouldn't allow us to pass the board to the p1's move method and hence no way to check for the validity of the move...

Comment: Yes you can :) There are many ways to kill a cat, specially in programming. In this case, rather than passing the board to p1's move, you can pass p1's move to the board, where  the move will be validated inside the board. Anyways, rather than us doing the whole implementation, why don't you place your current code so that we can help you further in its revision. Through this way, we can do the edit using your perspective, since every programmer has their own styles and preferences..

Answer (score 0):

The way you are implementing it, every user is having his own board, which is not the case instead it should be the following:

Every `Game` should have:

> 1. 2 player
> 2. 1 board

Every `Board` should have:

> 1. grids

Every `Player` has:

> 1. sign

Every `Player` can:

> 1. move

In a `Game` player can:

> 1. win

now "should haves" are variables, and "can"s are method calls.

So basically here we are focussing on board to be same in both of the players. To do that we chose a common ground to declare board and players.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes I agree! But my question is how to implement this approach? Pass the board object to player's move method as an argument?

Comment: remember game has player and board, and in board you need to know players move and his sign, so on boards method called from game you need to pass your player.